# Change all positive values to negative and vice versa but in two different files

Tags: awk, sed

I have two data files `one.txt` and `two.txt` on a Linux system. I want to convert all positive values to negative in `one.txt` and vice versa for `two.txt`, but only on the first column. Please note that data contains zeroes also.

`one.txt` is like this:

```
   10 35.74
    8 35.74
    6 35.74
    4 35.74
    2 35.74
    0 35.74
```

`two.txt` like this

```
    -20 35.74
    -18 35.74
    -16 35.74
    -14 35.74
    -12 35.74
     -0 35.74
```

I want to change `one.txt` like this:

```
   -10 35.74
    -8 35.74
    -6 35.74
    -4 35.74
    -2 35.74
    -0 35.74
```

And similarly, I want to change all negative values to positive in `two.txt`

I tried `awk '$1 *= -1' file.txt` but it messed-up zero.

*I need to execute these two problems in two different processes. So, I prefer two different solutions/codes for each instead of doing in one step*

Comment: I meant 'positive values'. Sorry, for the confusion, if I made any.

Comment: @linux_lover, you can [edit] your question to clarify in cases like this (I just did it for you, but in general)

Comment: `awk '$1 *= -1'` flips negative to positive and the other way around at the same time, so if `one.txt` contains values that are already negative, they'll turn positive. Strictly speaking, that's not what you asked, but might of course be what you meant. You'd need something like `$1 > 0 {$1 *= -1} {print}` to only flip positive to negative.

Comment: Your test files do not illustrate the requirement. If a line in one.txt happened to be negative already, the requirement says to leave it negative (it only specifies to change positive values). All the suggested methods change negative values to positive, which is not given as a requirement. The exact converse problem applies to two.txt.

Comment: You show the line `-0 35.74` in  your expected output but accepted an answer that cannot produce a line that starts with `-0`, it'd output `0 35.74` for that line instead. Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and fix your example if it's wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A slight variant of your attempt will work:

```
awk '{ $1 *= -1 } 1' file.txt
```

The issue with `awk '$1 *= -1'` is that `$1 *= -1` is taken as a condition; its effect is applied, but then taken as a condition, so the line which was processed is output only if the result is non-zero.

Adding braces causes the multiplication to be applied to all lines, and the `1` on its own causes all lines to be printed. To avoid changing empty lines, you can add a condition to the multiplication:

```
awk 'NF { $1 *= -1 } 1' file.txt
```

If you’re using Gawk¹, you can check that the first column is a number before changing it:

```
awk 'typeof($1) == "strnum" { $1 *= -1 } 1' file.txt
```

---

<sup>¹ and there's no `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable in the environment</sup>

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I needed. Many thanks.

Comment: Upvote specifically for GNU/awk typeof(). TIL early.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a text parsing problem. Convert the first `-` on every line to a `+`:

```
$ sed 's/-/+/' two.txt 
    +20 35.74
    +18 35.74
    +16 35.74
    +14 35.74
    +12 35.74
     +0 35.74
```

And add a `-` before the first number on each line (your files seem to have leading whitespace):

```
$ sed -E 's/[0-9]/-&/' one.txt 
   -10 35.74
    -8 35.74
    -6 35.74
    -4 35.74
    -2 35.74
    -0 35.74
```

If your files don't have the leading whitespace shown in the question, you can simplify that to:

```
sed -E 's/^/-/' one.txt
```

In all cases, you can use `-i` to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i 's/-/+/' two.txt
sed -i -E 's/[0-9]/-&/' one.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for this `sed` solution. Worked nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Negative 0 doesn't apply to integers C data types. When a number doesn't have fractional part, awk converts  it to string as if with `printf("%ld")`.

To keep the sign of `-0`, you'd need something like:

```
awk '{$1 = sprintf("%g", -$1); print}'
```

Beware `%g` has 6 digit precision and will switch to engineering notation for large numbers. You can replace with `%15g` for instance for more precision.

You you can do it text-wise without converting back and forth between string and number with:

```
perl -pe 's{(-?)(?=\d)}{$1 ? "" : "-"}e'
```

Which would also has the benefit of not changing the spacing between the fields. You can also pass a `-i` option for `perl` to edit  the files in place (which then need to be passed as arguments, not stdin).

Comment: Thanks for this solution. This is also very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/ \([0-9]\)/-\1/' one.txt > output-one.txt
```

replaces the first occurrence of a space followed by a digit with a minus followed by the captured digit.

```
sed 's/-\([0-9]\)/ \1/' two.txt > output-two.txt
```

replaces the first occurrence of a minus followed by a digit with a space followed by the captured digit.

If you want to have explicit positive signs you can use

```
sed 's/-\([0-9]\)/+\1/' two.txt > output-two.txt
```

If you want to modify your input file and if your `sed` supports in-place editing you can use

```
sed -i 's/ \([0-9]\)/-\1/' one.txt
sed -i 's/-\([0-9]\)/ \1/' two.txt
sed -i 's/-\([0-9]\)/+\1/' two.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for this `sed` solution. very helpful also.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '!sub(/-/,"",$1){$1="-"$1} 1' one.txt
-10 35.74
-8 35.74
-6 35.74
-4 35.74
-2 35.74
-0 35.74

$ awk '!sub(/-/,"",$1){$1="-"$1} 1' two.txt
20 35.74
18 35.74
16 35.74
14 35.74
12 35.74
0 35.74
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a unified sed script which inverts
the signs of the numbers. You can supply both the files also in one go.
Gnu sed required.

```
sed -i -e '
  s/-/+/;t
  s/[0-9]/-&/
' file
```

Comment: That would change `1 -2` to `1 +2` instead of `-1 -2` though.

Comment: That scenario is not specified. It appears from the wording that first field is to be modified.